# Packet Tracer installiation stuck in progress

Tags: software-installation

I've been trying to install Packet Tracer and it showed me a licence agreement window. I selected "Ok" and clicked enter to confirm the licence agreement and it seemed to work ("Ok" changed to "OK" shown [on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTRck.png)), but the licence agreement window doesn't change to the next one (shown [here](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-packet-tracer-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)) and no progress has been made for around 1 hour. What can I do for it to make some progress and install correctly? Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm quite new to both Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: You have not said what version of Ubuntu you are using. Also is this the 8.1 version of Packet Tracer?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and this is the 8.1.1 version of Packet Tracer